# Refrigerator - power cord exposed copper wire

Tags: wiring, refrigerator, copper, adapter

There are multiple parts of exposed copper wiring on the power cord of my refrigerator. There are about 3 parts where the copper is exposed. I'm not really sure how it happened.

[image]

Can I wrap it in electrical tape and call it a day or should I go without plugging it back in until I can get it repaired ( probably another 2 weeks )

Note: apparently this fridge has been plugged into a 2 prong outlet with an adapter. I don't see a way around using this 2 prong outlet and getting electric work done right now is not an option. Is there a safer adapter I can use?

Comment: Mice is how it happen.  Can tape for now, but should replace cord as soon as possible.  The large section seems like the wire(copper) has also been chewed.  The two prong adapter is only good if the box the outlet is in, is grounded.  Can replace the two prong outlet with a GFCI outlet for safety.

Answer (score 4):

Mice is how it happen.  Mice have been chewing on the wire.  You got mice.

Can tape for now, but should replace cord as soon as possible. The large section seems like the wire(copper) has also been chewed.  Less copper can mean the wire could heat up more.

The two prong adapter is only good if the box the outlet is in, is grounded. The adapter works if a short wire or prong is attached to the centre screw holding the face plate.

The box will be grounded if there is a bare/or green wire attached to it, or the wires are in a metal conduit attached to the box.

Can replace the two prong outlet with a GFCI outlet for safety.

Comment: But beware: While a GFCI **will** provide equivalent safety to grounding (and in fact, more safety in many instances), it is also more likely to have a False Positive = "nuisance trip". The risk is that if you don't find out until too late then you may end up with spoiled food, or even worse food that you don't even know is spoiled. Likely a mouse chew would trip the GFCI where it won't trip the regular breaker - you get back a day later and everything is spoiled.